# Grouped SELECT query by number of staff supervised

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SELECT query for the following User table that counts how many other people a user supervises, then returns their name alongside the number of people they supervise as two columns, 'SupervisorName' and 'NoStaff':

```
CREATE TABLE User (
userID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
userName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
dateOfJoin DATE NOT NULL,
DepIDREF VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
userSupervisor VARCHAR(10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userID),
FOREIGN KEY (DepIDREF)
REFERENCES Department (DepID)
);

INSERT INTO User VALUES 
('a10', 'Ava Perrier', '1983-06-17', 'dep10', 'e8'),
('e11', 'Ella Moncada', '1982-02-15', 'dep20', 'k1'),
('e8', 'Emily Afonso', '1985-01-12', 'dep40', 't6'),
('h3', 'Harry Moncada', '1990-03-25', 'dep10', 'null'),
('i9', 'Isla Schmitt', '1984-07-18', 'dep40', 'e8'),
('j2', 'Jack Simpson', '1985-07-30', 'dep10', 'k1'),
('k1','Karim Mualla','1986-10-16','dep10', 'null'),
('n4', 'Noah Domingues', '1989-12-05', 'dep20', 'k1'),
('o7', 'Oscar Cruz', '1986-09-11', 'dep40', 't6'),
('t6','Thomas Carvalho', '1987-04-27', 'dep30', 'w5'),
('w5', 'William Batista', '1988-05-22', 'dep20', 'h3');
```

The current query I have written is as follows:

```
SELECT userName AS SupervisorName, count(userID) AS NoStaff 
FROM User WHERE userSupervisor IS NOT NULL GROUP BY userSupervisor;
```

However the result of this query seems to return the names of everyone who ISN'T supervising someone along with a number that I can't quite understand the calculation of. I have tried several variations on this query, swapping around userID and userSupervisor, etc, but mostly I get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated (I find SQL very confusing...).

Comment: :-) - there is no NULL in your table. you put the STRING 'null' in it . USe the word NULL without quotes

Comment: Is this an interview question? :P

Comment: ah thanks for the spot! however after changing that I still have an issue in that two of the supervisors (Karim, who supervises 3 people and Harry who supervises 1) is missing from the table. I'm assuming this is because of my NOT NULL condition. but if I take that out, I'm back to having random count numbers again.

Comment: no it is definitely not an interview question. I'm a first year in university and I already know I'm never going to apply for a database related job...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to self-join the `user` table on itself using the `userid` and `userSupervisor` fields to get the list of users supervised by a superviosor and then you can do the group by:

```
select u1.userid, u1.userName as supervisor, count(u2.userid) as no_staff
from user u1
left join user u2 on u1.userid=u2.userSupervisor
group by u1.userid, u1.userName
```

If you would like to get the list of only those users, that supervise at least 1 other user, then change the `left join` to `inner join`.

Comment: ah I didn't even consider using a join, my head was stuck in 'select' mode. thank you very much, I will try and remember to try a join next time I get stuck like this.